# What does an int value returned by InputStream.read() represent?

Tags: java, byte, primitive-types

The documentation says `read()` returns the `byte` as an `int` value between `0` and `255`.

What does this value represent?

Comment: It's the byte in the input...

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read--), in the sentence before the one you mention, states that the value is "the next byte of data from the input stream."

Comment: @chrylis What? Of course it is. But what does the value mean. How is the int value determined?

Comment: static int  SIZE
The number of bits used to represent a byte value in two's complement binary form. ----- Is this the value being returned?

Comment: Yes it is the next byte of data from the stream. But what does the int value for that byte mean and how is it determined? Is it the size of the byte?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In two's complement, the number `-1` is represented by all bits set to a 1.

Here is a byte value of `-1`:*

```
1111 1111
```

Here is an int value of `-1`:*

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

If we take the byte value of `-1` and store it in an int without extending the sign, it becomes `255`:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111
```

This is just the behavior of two's complement. Storing bytes in an int leaves us leftover bits we can use to indicate other things.

So input stream returns byte values from `0`-`255`, and `-1` to indicate end of stream. To get the byte values, cast the int to a byte:

```
int byteAsInt = inputStream.read();
if(byteAsInt > -1) {
     byte byteValue = (byte)byteAsInt;

     // use the byte
}
```

The int values `128`-`255` will become interpreted as negative numbers when it is casted to the byte. Alternatively, you can perform "unsigned" arithmetic on the int.

The bytes themselves can mean anything. For example if they are from a `.txt` file, they are probably straight ASCII codes. Other formats can be much more complicated.

---

* [4.2:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2)

> The integral types are `byte`, `short`, `int`, and `long`, whose values are 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit signed two's-complement integers, respectively […].

Comment: Thank you. I need to understand to two's complement

Comment: Is this just an example or where is stated that the returned int has 32bit? Isn't the only fixed and guaranteed length on "every" computer a char consisting of 8bit? Can not find anything related to the size of the returned int in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) Please post a source with explanation for your statement.

Comment: @Mike The size of primitive types in Java is given by the specification. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2 You may be thinking of some other languages e.g. C and C++ where sizes are not precisely defined, but it's not like this in Java. Java requires that `int` is 32 bits.

Answer (score 0):

read() reads the next byte and then return it.

The reason it return it as an int, instead of a byte as you would expect, is that a byte is signed(Have values between -127 and 128) so it can't be used to return a value between 0-255

Comment: I find this confusing because I am using this on a large binary file at the moment and it is returning int values higher than 128? Ie it is returning values between 0 -255

Comment: A (unsigned) byte, is a value between 0 and 255. Why do you find that confusing?

Comment: Because you just said it is returning it as an int and not a byte because it is signed, but it is sending it as values between 0 - 255 which means it is unsigned, and by your logic shouldn't be returning as an int?

Comment: The byte type is signed in java(-127 to 128), and the read method want to return an unsigned byte(0-255) value, so it can't use the java byte type to do that. So it read 8 bits and convert that to a number between 0 and 255. This number is then returned in a java int.

Answer (score 0):

It represents the next byte of data. The reason it returns an `int` and not a `byte` is that byte type is between -128 and 127, and this method uses the value -1 to indicate the end of the stream.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't "represent" anything. It's whatever the InputStream's next byte is.

For instance, a `FileInputStream` lets you read the bytes from a file. If the first byte in that file is 37, then `read()` will return 37. If the second byte in the file is 231, then the second call to `read()` will return 231. The bytes are returned as unsigned values, meaning that each byte can have a value between 0 and 255 (inclusive).

If the value is non-negative and you want it as a `byte`, you can just cast it:

```
int nextByteAsInt = inputStream.read();
if (nextByteAsInt >= 0) {
    byte nextByte = (byte) nextByteAsInt;
    doSomethingWithByte(nextByte);
} else {
    inputStreamIsFinished();
}
```

When all of the file has been read, `read()` will return -1. The reason `read()` doesn't just return a `byte` is that if needs to be able to return that -1 to represent that end of stream.

To get at what the bytes "mean," you have to know their context -- what you're reading. A byte from a text file will mean one thing, a file from a compressed or binary file will mean another, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`Read()` returns the next byte in the byte stream, converted to an unsigned int.  When a byte is converted to an unsigned integer, it will be between `0` and `255`, since the bits are `1+2+4+8+16+32+64+128 = 255`.  What it represents depends on what kind of data was converted to binary and sent over the byte stream.

This isn't in your question; so I didn't include it in my original answer, but it seems to be where this question often comes from:

It is important to note that `Read()` will return `-1` to indicate end of stream.  `0` to `255` represents all the possible states of the next byte (8 bits), but `Read()` returns a 32-bit two's complement integer.  This means that the returned byte will take up the first 8 bits, leaving the rest of the 32 bits of the retuned integer all `0`.  So for end of stream, `Read()` returns 32 bits all set to `1`, which represents `-1` in two's complement.